# How to make a Qt build from sources portable?

Tags: qt

How can I make a Qt build that I built with the `-prefix` parameter portable to other machines? When I copy my build over to a location on a different machine which differs from the location is specified for `-prefix` on the build machine `qmake` complains about not being able to find files and from the error messages it is clear that the files are being searched for in the directory that was used as the `-prefix` parameter on the original build machine. I mean, the builds that come from the Qt maintenance tool obviously do not have this problem since they do not know where they will be installed at.

My configure line is `configure.bat -prefix C:\Development\qt-5.8.0-msvc2015-x86 -opensource -debug-and-release -nomake examples -confirm-license`

Side question - when I use this build for Visual Studio with this build Qt cannot find `qwindows.dll` platform plugin. I copied it over to the binary folder under `platforms` and it works, but how does the installed Qt version get around this without copying anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the builds that come from the Qt maintenance tool obviously do not have this problem since they do not know where they will be installed at.

They do have that problem, and the maintenance tool works around it by binary patching the installation paths. You could do so as well. The paths are stored with empty space appended to facilitate this.

There's nothing you need to do to the build itself. Only after you unzip the build on the target machine, you need to patch it. A rudimentary patcher iterates all the files, and replaces the install path prefix with the real path.

Comment: Thanks, maybe you can give a side note on the plugins issue?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your plugins issue. As long as your application can find the Qt installation (e.g. by adding `QTDIR\bin` to `PATH`), it will find the plugins as well.

Answer (score 0):

(Added for other people looking fo a similar answer)

There is another way that al least in Linux works great, but I haven't tried it in windows (it also looks like this feature might have been disabled in Qt 6).

It is using `qt.conf`.

It is a text file you need to put in the same directory as qmake, and supports roughly the same variables as the build configuration, plus some extras, and one of the nice things is that at least in linux it supports relative paths (from qmake directory to the paths where the respective components of the resulting build are. You might need to experiment with forward vs back slashes,etc.). A basic example you can try is

```
[Paths]
Prefix:<path-to-QtCore-dynamic-library>
```

And for more info about the possibilities you can take a [look at this document](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/software/texmaker_v5.0.2/qt57/doc/qtdoc/qt-conf.html)

A list of some supported variables is:

```
Prefix  - path to QtCore dynamic library
Documentation - doc
Headers - include
Libraries - lib
LibraryExecutables - libexec
Binaries - bin
Plugins - plugins
Imports - imports
Qml2Imports - qml
ArchData    .
Data    .
Translations    translations
Examples    examples
Tests   tests
Settings    .
```

You will find most of these directories inside your resulting Qt build

When I was looking into this it took me many hours find information about it, and it looks like the documentation of this feature is slowly disappearing.